# Not passing proper parameters Parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am developing an application using Parse.com

According to it's error system, it's saying I'm not passing the proper parameters when trying to "login."

Here is my code:

```
function signInUser() {

        Parse.initialize("", "");

        var username = this.$("#signin-username").val();
        var password = this.$("#signin-password").val();

        Parse.User.logIn(username, password, {
            success: function(user) {
                alert("You successfully logged in!");
            },
             error: function(user, error) {
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }
    });
```

}

Comment: AGLearner: please use the `parse.com` tag for `parse.com` questions. The `parsing` tag is for something quite different.

Comment: Use `$()` instead of `this.$()`

Comment: @thefrontender that still doesnt work

Comment: Are you sure that both username and password are correctly set? Regardless of $() or this.$() being the correct choice, you should log the value to make sure you're actually getting what you expect. Also, can you post the full error returned by Parse?

Answer (score 0):

I was board at work so I made up a simple register and login [so you can compare with your code with mine.](http://jsbin.com/eroqig/1/edit)